# Foundation on Diophantine Analysis and Number Theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, soft-question, diophantine-equations, big-list

I want to read particularly about diophantine Analysis and Elementary Number Theory from a novice level.

The books which I found on net:

1. A Guide to Elementary Number Theory by Underwood Dudley
2. Diophantine Analysis by Robert Daniel Carmichael
3. Diophantine Analysis by Jorn Steuding

Help me with good suggestions as I think M.SE. has people from novice to professional users.

Thanks.

P.S. I have searched M.SE. for this type of question, I didn't find any. If you know someone, you may give the link.

Comment: Perhaps you could give some detail about the type of problems you find interesting. I am not entirely sure what to expect from the title Diophantine Analysis.

Answer (score 1):

A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory by Ireland and Rosen is a great book. Definitely one of the best. As for Diophantine analysis, well that can mean a few things. Lang has a good book on Diophantine approximations. I suspect that going through a book like Ireland and Rosen's will give you a better idea of what it is, specifically, that you're looking for

Comment: thanks :). .that was helpful

Answer (score 1):

Concerning Diophantine analysis I learned much in a nice little book of Edward Burger : ['Exploring the Number Jungle'](http://books.google.com/books?id=2l_PKJ5075kC&pg=PA1).

Concerning Number Theory from a novice level the venerable Hardy & Wright's ['Introduction to Number Theory'](http://books.google.com/books?id=rey9wfSaJ9EC&pg=PA1) had to be cited.